# Birt report parameter show blank in all browser

Tags: browser, report, birt

i have a problem on running birt report on browser, the report parameter show blank. I have tested in eclipse design area, it working well, but when I deploy into tomcat server, and run in browser, it didnt show any data in the parameter box.

My system running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
I tested on browser IE7, Chrome, Mozilla

Please help, thanks.

[image]

*my problem solve: 
I found out i forgot to import sqljdbc.jar into tomcat lib, is my fault.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and except it.  You may have to wait 24 hours after you posted before you are allowed to answer your own question.